# Print dates in date range linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, date

I am new to linux. How can I print and store date in given date range.

For example  I have startdate=2013-03-01 and enddate = 2013-03-25 ; I want to print all date in that range.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20):

As long as the dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format, you can compare them lexicographically, and let `date` do the calendar arithmetic without converting to seconds first:

```
startdate=2013-03-15
enddate=2013-04-14

curr="$startdate"
while true; do
    echo "$curr"
    [ "$curr" \< "$enddate" ] || break
    curr=$( date +%Y-%m-%d --date "$curr +1 day" )
done
```

With `[ ... ]`, you need to escape the `<` to avoid confusion with the input redirection operator.

This does have the wart of printing the start date if it is greater than the end date.

Comment: So, just do the `echo "$curr"` after the test ;). `date --date "$curr +1 day"` is   nicer than the `let cur=..`

Comment: It's probably better to put this in a for loop rather than a while loop to be safe.  If you parameterize your startdate and enddate within a script, with the loop running max of say 366 times or 1000 times.  This will keep it from infinitely looping.

Answer (score 9):

An alternate if you want 'recent' dates is:

```
echo {100..1} | xargs -I{} -d ' ' date --date={}' days ago' +"%Y-%m-%d"
```

Obviously won't work for arbitrary date ranges.

Comment: this is close of the best answer I think, I made a change with it:

    $ startdate='2016-03-01'; echo {0..10} | xargs -I{} -d ' ' date --date="$startdate +"{}" days" +"%Y-%m-%d"
    2016-03-01
    2016-03-02
    2016-03-03
    ....

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to use `dateseq` from `dateutils` (http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/#dateseq):

```
$ dateseq 2013-03-01 2013-03-25
2013-03-01
2013-03-02
2013-03-03
2013-03-04
2013-03-05
2013-03-06
2013-03-07
2013-03-08
2013-03-09
2013-03-10
2013-03-11
2013-03-12
2013-03-13
2013-03-14
2013-03-15
2013-03-16
2013-03-17
2013-03-18
2013-03-19
2013-03-20
2013-03-21
2013-03-22
2013-03-23
2013-03-24
2013-03-25
```

Comment: Nice!  In Vim: `:read ! dateseq 2018-12-04 2019-12-31`. `:read` appends output to current buffer (file); `!` executes the external (BASH) command (`dateseq ...`).

Comment: This was huge for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `date` to convert your dates to seconds, do a little maths and convert back:

```
#/bin/bash

dstart=2013-03-01
dend=2013-03-25
# convert in seconds sinch the epoch:
start=$(date -d$dstart +%s)
end=$(date -d$dend +%s)
cur=$start

while [ $cur -le $end ]; do
    # convert seconds to date:
    date -d@$cur +%Y-%m-%d
    let cur+=24*60*60
done
```

See `man date` for more info on date parameters..

Answer (score 1):

Slightly improved version

```
#!/bin/bash
startdate=2013-03-15
enddate=2013-04-14

curr="$startdate"
while true; do
    [ "$curr" \< "$enddate" ] || { echo "$curr"; break; }
    echo "$curr"
    curr=$( date +%Y-%m-%d --date "$curr +1 day" )
done
```

Answer (score 1):

one line version:

```sh
seq 0 24 | xargs -I {} date  +"%Y-%m-%d" -d '20130301 {}day'

# this version is ok if the dates not cross next month
seq -f'%.f'  20130301 20130325
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

A simple demo

```
start_date="20191021"                                                                        
end_date="20191025"                                                                          
dates=()                                                                                     
while [[ "${start_date}" != "${end_date}" ]];do                                              
  formatted_date=$(date -d "${start_date}" +"%Y%m%d")                                        
  dates+=( "${formatted_date}" )                                                                                                                                
  start_date=$(date -d "$start_date +1 day" +"%Y%m%d")                                       
done
```